# why does a pg connection pool create two idle connections in flask?

Tags: python, flask, psycopg2

I'm building a flask app for learning and development purposes. everything works a charm and I'm quickly getting the hang of things. what bugs me, is the number of connections created based on the parameters I provide. without wishing to go in discussions about this, I'm not interested in sqlalchemy!

it's a postgres connection pool with minconn = 1 and maxconn = 10. I expect the app to create one connection when it starts, which it does. I also have a before_request() function, to grab a connection from the pool. there's also a teardown_request() to put the connection back after each request, as per code below.

I would expect the ONE connection that's created when the app starts to be the connection that gets put in g before a request, and the same connection to be put back in the pool after each request, hence no more than 1 connection at any given time. for some reason, I always have two connections active (well, idle) in pgadmin (no, the pgadmin connection is separate and well tagged). what is going on here, why doesn't my logic apply?

if it helps, changing minconn to 2 results in 4! connections at startup.

```
from flask import current_app, g
from psycopg2.extras import DictCursor
from psycopg2 import pool
import psycopg2



def database_connection(app):
    dsn = f'''postgresql://{current_app.config['SQL_USERNAME']}:{current_app.config['SQL_PASSWORD']}@{current_app.config['SQL_HOST']}:{current_app.config['SQL_PORT']}/{current_app.config['SQL_DATABASE']}'''
    pool = psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool(minconn = current_app.config['SQL_MINCONN'], maxconn = current_app.config['SQL_MAXCONN'], dsn = dsn)

    @app.before_request
    def open_connection():
        if 'connection' not in g:
            g.connection = pool.getconn()
            g.connection.autocommit = True
            g.cursor = g.connection.cursor(cursor_factory = DictCursor)

    @app.teardown_request
    def close_connection(response):
        g.cursor.close()
        g.connection = g.pop('connection', None)
        if g.connection is not None:
            pool.putconn(g.connection)

        return response
```

Comment: Just a guess but from here [Pool](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/pool.html): *SimpleConnectionPool A connection pool that can’t be shared across different threads. 
**Note** This pool class is useful only for single-threaded applications.* vs *ThreadedConnectionPool  **Note** This pool class can be safely used in multi-threaded applications.*

Comment: I tried using a threaded connection pool, it's exactly the same behaviour. I seem to be missing something, unless this is expected behaviour and it's all ok. thanks anyway!